# SQL Server, Datagrid(s): Select from, update fields in all tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

I want to update ALL tables in my sql server that have a specific field with a datagrid on a rowchanged event.

I also thought about using parent and child keys, But there are at minimal, 2 values that determine the items uniqueness. Along with that the Master Sheet MUST HAVE duplicate values with only 1 column discerning where it is on the slave tables.

**I.E.** 
Item > Item Location(s) (*The item can be spit and physically distributed*)

Alternatively I thought about using command builder, but I couldn't think of a logical way of doing this with it.

However I'm not sure how the statement would go..
Here's the Idea:

This also has to include all values on the master table.

```
UPDATE "alltables" SET " + iOne + "," + iTwo + " WHERE column1="previous entry"
```

**How I was trying to approach it:**

```
 private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string iOne = dgMasterGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value + string.Empty;
    string iTwo = dgMasterGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value + string.Empty;
    string iThree = dgMasterGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value + string.Empty;

    string slaveiOne = dgSlave1GridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value + string.Empty;
    string slaveiTwo = dgSlave1GridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value + string.Empty;
    string slaveiThree = dgSlave1GridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value + string.Empty;

    try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connection.MTRDataBaseConn))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        // ???????????????  UPDATE STATEMENT  ???????????????
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE "alltables" SET " + iOne + "," + iTwo + " WHERE column1="previous entry";

        cmd.Connection = con;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item1", iOne);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item2", iTwo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item3", iThree);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Information has been submitted");

    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only update one table in a single update statement. If you want to update multiple tables, you must write multiple update statements.

Comment: Slight detour but you might want to take a peek at this article. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @ZoharPeled Ok, The only issue with that, is the user can create additional slave tables and input information.

How would I run a loop to run in conjunction with a single statement across all tables?

Comment: 'alltables' is a variable that you can change in your code dynamically to enumerate through all the tables.  You would need to get all the tab le names from the database using schema command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in tow ways:

1- through a stored procedure that update your tables one by one, you need to send your new values as parameters...

2- through .net code if you have a datasets for your tables, you can just user SQLDataAdapter with  .Update()  ....

---

this update; i use this function on my code to update multiple dataset using data adapter with begin transaction,, commit and roolback on error.. hope this will help you...

```
    public bool Update_DS(ArrayList strTableName, ArrayList objSqlDataAdapter, ArrayList objDataSet)
    {
        bool ErrorOccured = false;
        try
        {
            _LastException = null;
            objSqlTransaction = objSqlConnection.BeginTransaction();

            for (int i = 0; i < objSqlDataAdapter.Count; i++)
            {
                SqlDataAdapter objDATemp = (SqlDataAdapter)objSqlDataAdapter[i];

                //objDATemp.SelectCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(objDATemp).getse();
                objDATemp.SelectCommand.Transaction = objSqlTransaction;
                objDATemp.SelectCommand.Connection = objSqlConnection;

                objDATemp.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(objDATemp).GetUpdateCommand();
                objDATemp.UpdateCommand.Transaction = objSqlTransaction;
                objDATemp.UpdateCommand.Connection = objSqlConnection;

                objDATemp.InsertCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(objDATemp).GetInsertCommand();
                objDATemp.InsertCommand.Transaction = objSqlTransaction;
                objDATemp.InsertCommand.Connection = objSqlConnection;

                objDATemp.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(objDATemp).GetDeleteCommand();
                objDATemp.DeleteCommand.Transaction = objSqlTransaction;
                objDATemp.DeleteCommand.Connection = objSqlConnection;

                objDATemp.Update((DataSet)objDataSet[i], strTableName[i].ToString());
            }
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _LastException = ex;
            ErrorOccured = true;
            //OnError(ex);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (ErrorOccured)
                objSqlTransaction.Rollback();
            else
                objSqlTransaction.Commit();

            if (objSqlCommand != null)
            {
                objSqlCommand.Dispose();
                objSqlCommand = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: .Update(); won't update across all fields that match in ALL tables, right?

Comment: THANKS!! This helps a lot.